# Setting logic in Z3 .Net API

Tags: z3

This is a very small example which shows one of the problems I have:

```
class Z3Tester
    {
        private Context cICtx;
        private Solver cISolver; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Z3Tester lZ3Tester = new Z3Tester();
            lZ3Tester.Test_Z3();
        }

        public void Test_Z3()
        {
            BoolExpr lA = cICtx.MkBoolConst("A");
            BoolExpr lB = cICtx.MkBoolConst("B");
            cISolver.Push();
            BoolExpr lConstraint1 = cICtx.MkBoolConst("Constraint1");
            cISolver.AssertAndTrack(lA, lConstraint1);
            cISolver.ToString();
            cISolver.Check(lConstraint1);
        }

        public Z3Tester()
        {
            cICtx = new Context(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "proof", "true" } });
            using (cICtx)
                this.cISolver = cICtx.MkSolver("QF_FD");
```

In this code when I come to the `cISolver.Check(lConstraint1);` line I get the AccessViolationException... .

Comment: creates a solver object that uses configurations for the specified logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the Context object, (in Context.cs):

```
  public Solver MkSolver(string logic)
```

it creates a solver object that uses configurations for the specified logic.

Comment: I want to set the logic in Z3 .Net API. For that I use the
 `Public Solver MkSolver(string Logic)` 
function to set the logic to "QF_FD".
But when I do this later on in the code when I want to use functions like:

    Solver.Push()
or

    Solver.Check(boolExpr)
I get the error:

    SystemAccessViolationException:...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you call other functions (not solver related ones), e.g., to get the version string? If you can't, this is most likely a problem with the native library that the system refuses to load (for various reasons).

Comment: So what you are saying is that if I set the logic of a solver I can't use some of its functions which I mentioned before?

Comment: No. Either your setup is broken, or Z3 is broken. I need more information to help you. (But yes, there are some settings that enable/disable some functionality, but that has nothing to do with the current problem.) Can you call .ToString() on your solver object?